# One liner mkdir with directory naming as days?

Tags: date, mkdir

How can I create directories named as days of the week (i.e Monday, Tuesday, .... Saturday) inside a directory like /tmp/ in one command only?

Like combination of `mkdir` with `date +%A` or any other.

```
mkdir -p /tmp/"$(date +%A)"  --->  /tmp/Tuesday
```

Should be as below after command executes.

```
/tmp/Monday
/tmp/Tuesday
.
.
.
/tmp/Saturday
```

I want this in a single command, not a script.

Comment: `mkdir Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following 'command' to get the desired result:

```
for i in {1..7}; do mkdir /tmp/$(date +"%A" --date "$i days ago"); done
```

Comment: (assuming GNU `date` (and that POSIXLY_CORRECT is not in the environment) and `zsh` or recent versions of `ksh93`/`bash`/`yash -o brace-expand` and that `$IFS` was not modified and that you're not in a locale (like `kw_GB.UTF-8`) where day names contain blanks or wildcard characters).

Comment: If run today Tuesday 2017-03-28 at 00:30 in the morning in most of Europe, if would be missing `Sunday` as `1 days ago` would be `Monday 2017-03-27 00:30` and `2 days ago` would be `Saturday 2017-03-25 23:30` because of the clock change on Sunday morning. `Monday` would be listed twice as `7 days ago` would be `Monday 2017-03-20 23:30`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use brace expansion:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/{Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday}
```

The above is equivalent to this (which is also a single command):

```
mkdir -p /tmp/Sunday /tmp/Monday /tmp/Tuesday /tmp/Wednesday /tmp/Thursday /tmp/Friday /tmp/Saturday
```

Comment: Using Brace expansion is simple & useful trick. Glad to know this :)

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`:

```
zmodload zsh/langinfo # if not already loaded
mkdir /tmp/${(v)^langinfo[(I)DAY_*]}
```

That uses day names in your locale. As a single command:

```
zsh -c 'zmodload zsh/langinfo && mkdir /tmp/${(v)^langinfo[(I)DAY_*]}'
```

`$langinfo` is a special associative array that exposes some locale settings including day names. `$langinfo[(I)DAY_*]` would output the keys of that array that match `DAY_*` (that is `DAY_1`, `DAY_2`...). With the `(v)` parameter expansion flag, we expand the values for those keys instead. `^` distributes those elements so that it becomes `/tmp/value1`, `/tmp/value2`...

With any POSIX-like shell, you can also do:

```
(cd /tmp && IFS=';' && set -o noglob && mkdir $(locale day))
```

`locale day` returns a `;`-separated list of day names in the current locale. We use the split+glob operator on it (leave the `$(...)` command substitution unquoted) after having disabled the *glob* part (`set -o noglob`) and tuned the *split* part to split on `;` (`IFS=';'`).

Comment: Thanks for nice detailed explanation. Helps at lot for gaining something  new.